# CryptoNight can mine monero?

Tags: cryptonight

Thanks in advance for all answers

at first I am new in this business. 
I want to buy Baikal N240 which has Algorithm CryptoNight and CryptoNight-lite. I want Mine Monero.

My question is, can we mined Monero Algorithm CryptoNight? or must need CryptoNight variant 1 (CNv1)?

or can I go with any good product for mine? if any good profitable product than please give me suggestion

Thanks

---

I really salute you from bottom of my heart. 
that means I should't buy CryptoNight algorithm hardware?
please could you suggest me which hardware is profitable for mining.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current algorithm is CryptoNightV1 [edit: now Cryptonight v4 as of may 2019], and will change in the future.
If you want to mine with ASIC or FPGA, you're looking at the wrong cryptocurrency.
Monero will change its algo at every network upgrade to remain ASIC and FPGA-resistant, and help the decentralization through the smaller player (CPU & GPU) wider participation.

With a CryptoNight ASIC/FPGA you could mine some XMC along with other ASICs.

Edit: If you want to mine Monero, then CPU (AMD ryzen series) and GPU (AMD RX550 and newer) are good hardware.
If you have enough Money, choose AMD Vega 56/64 GPUs.

Comment: FPGA's are upgradable. (hence the FP: field programmable)  ASIC are a one time dealio.  FPGAs might be doable, but memory constraints might make them unusable for CN/CN7

Comment: Algo change would be done to ban FPGA architecture. You can reprogram an FPGA, not add a new layer of instruction or memory on the fly.